# django implementing simple vistor log

Tags: python, django, logging

I'm fair new to Django and I am trying to log visitor for my blog. I'm using generic view for my blog and here is part of code:

```
#blog/urls.py

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    #index
    url(r'^(?P<page>\d+)?/?$', PostListView.as_view(
        model=Post,
        paginate_by=3,
        )),

    #individual post
    url(r'^(?P<pub_date__year>\d{4})/(?P<pub_date__month>\d{1,2})/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$', 
        DetailView.as_view(model=Post,)),

    #cat
    url(r'^category/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$', CategoryListView.as_view(
        paginate_by=3,
        model=Category,
        )),

    #tag
    url(r'^tag/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$', TagListView.as_view(
        paginate_by=3,
        model=Tag,
        )),
```

and I wrote a simple model for visitor log:

```
#tasks/models.py

class Visitor(models.Model):
    visit_stamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    referer = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    ip = models.IPAddressField(blank=True)
    user_agent = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    page = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

and its view:

```
#tasks/views.py

def log(request, page):
    try:
        hit = Visitor()
        hit.page = page
        hit.ip = request.META.get('REMOTE ADDR', '')
        hit.last_visit = datetime.now()
        hit.referer = request.META.get('HTTP REFERER', '')
        hit.user_agent = request.META.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT', '')
        hit.save()

    except IntegrityError:
        pass

def tracking(request, page):
    log(request, page)
    return render_to_response(page)
```

My question is how and where can I call this methods so that I can log a user is visiting a specific page. I'd appreciate any advices.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I assume you don't have access to the apache (or whatever host is running your django app) logs and/or you want to eventually add other things and/or you want it available in the database, as otherwise, you can skip a lot of work and just grep the logs.

Anyways, I'd recommend rewriting track to work as a decorator (and adjust log as you need it... note that I believe you can get the URL from the request object versus passing it in as a page value in case you want to know which specific instance was visited).  There are also ways you could probably do this with middleware, but this gives you a pretty good mix of simplicity and ability to control which views get logged.

To borrow an example from http://www.djangofoo.com/253/writing-django-decorators

```
def track(page):
    def decorator(func):
        def inner_decorator(request, *args, **kwargs):
            log(request, page)
            return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return wraps(func)(inner_decorator)
    return decorator
```

And then in your urls (or you can also do @track to decorate function based views)

```
url(r'^(?P<page>\d+)?/?$', track("index")(PostListView.as_view(
        model=Post,
        paginate_by=3,
        ))),
url(r'^someregexp$', track("pagename")(SomeListView.as_view(
        model=Post,
        paginate_by=3,
        ))),
```

Edit: meant to add.  Do note that in general, GET requests are supposed to be idempotent; logging is a gray area but the main thing to keep in mind is that some requests may not get logged as you might expect if the page is cached (for Posts this shouldn't be an issue)

Comment: actually url part makes me more confused :|. I went to kinda different approach that I create generic object for all models and in `get_context_data` I create Visitor model so that everytime user visit any pages log will be created. Is this bad idea?

Comment: I personally wouldn't like to inherit your code, just because at least my mental picture of how that would work, this violates many of the design philosophies of Django (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/misc/design-philosophies/).  Note that you could argue even my way violates DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) a little bit, but if you literally wanted to log every request, you probably want to do this as middleware and I haven't had to do this so I can't provide good examples.

Comment: On the other hand, my experience having started developing with Django and then leading folks who learn Django is that folks start out doing stuff the hard way and as they grok (deeply understand) Django's philosphy, they can refactor stuff away